# Ignoring \belowdisplayshortskip or \belowdisplayskip at the end of an environment: how to do it?

Tags: math-mode, environments, vertical-spacing, belowdisplayskip

I would like to ignore `\belowdisplayshortskip` or `\belowdisplayskip` when it is at the end of a given environment.

In the MWE below, I am looking for a command `\lookedForCommand` that delete the extra space avec `\[ ... \]` in the third occurence of `\begin{test} ... \end{test}` but not in the second.

Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\def\lookedForCommand{}

\newenvironment{test}{\bigskip xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \smallskip\par}{\lookedForCommand\par\smallskip xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \bigskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
We know that $1+1=2$.
\end{test}

\begin{test}
We know that \[1+1=2\]
and $1+2=3$.
\end{test}

\begin{test}
We know that \[1+1=2.\]
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

Someone has posted his solution and I'm using it (without problem so far). But since then he has deleted it! I put here his code. I will open a bounty for this questions if there are no answer. I think it is an interesting question for all the community.

```
\def\removeBelowDisplayskip
{\par%
 \ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayshortskip\vskip-\lastskip\fi%
 \ifdim\lastskip=\belowdisplayskip\vskip-\lastskip\fi
 }
```

Comment: I don't think the `\par` is strictly necessary (and possibly not desirable), you should be able to just do `\ifvmode\unskip\fi` to remove the last vertical skip in the environment.

Comment: Also, your spacing above and below should be managed by the environment itself, not done outside the environment.